# can't use link styles for several specific ids

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, styles

In my css it seems i can't use several different link styles in multiple id selectors.
This is how my css looks now:

```
    #embed a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active
    {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: underline; 
    }
    #header a:link, a:visited, a:active
    {
    color: #777777;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

It only follows "#header a:link, a:visited, a:active".
Both #embed and #header refers to two different divs in the html, both are separate from each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS descendant selectors do not distribute over `,`s.
You need to repeat `#header ​` after each `,`, or the later selectors will apply to all `a`s.

Answer (score 0):

the css code shouldn't it be like this ?

```
#embed a:link, #embed a:visited, #embed a:hover, #embed a:active
```

Ju